# How to POST data to a Django Form that contains checkboxes

Tags: django, django-forms, django-testing, django-unittest

I have a problem when I am testing my registration form in Django. I am trying to make a POST request but I cannot select a checkbox field.

```
self.response = self.client.post(url, {
        'username': 'testuser',
        'password': 'testuserpassword',
        'first_name': 'testtt',
        'last_name': 'userrr',
        'image': '',
        'email': 'testuser@gmail.com',
        'gender': 'M',
        'dob': '10/10/1996',
        'hobby': 'Fishing'
    })
```

This is my line of code. The problem is at Hobby. The registration page is made of two forms. A profile form and a hobby form. There is a many-to-many relationship between Profile and Hobby models.

When I make the above POST request, I get this (Select a valid choice):

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you post the object you're sending in the network request?

Comment: Also, is your 'hobby' field a fk? You're posting a string, and the values of your checkboxes are integers. One of the two is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the screenshot you've posted, the value for each hobby checkbox corresponds to an integer - 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. That would imply that the backend is expecting the hobby ID to be transmitted in the form. However, the test is not sending the hobby ID, it's sending the name.

Change the name to the corresponding ID - e.g.

```
self.response = self.client.post(url, {
        ...
        'hobby': 1  # Fishing
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My mistake was that I forgot that tests do not have access to the real database. Thus, I had to create a new hobby object in the tests.py file and then use the id. 

However, because you are close to the answer I will accept this answer.